# Is memorizing the Quran easy if you know Arabic?

Tags: quran, arabic, quran-recitation, tajweed, quran-memorization

I do not understand Arabic at all.

Is memorizing Quran easier if you know the Arabic language?

If so should I learn Arabic first before starting to memorize the Surahs of the Quran. What is the best approach?

[**Please Note**: I would like to get an expert advise from a Hafiz who's mother tongue is not Arabic. Such a person best suits my situation. Not just answers based on personal opinions]

By the way is there a way to authenticate such an answer ?

Comment: Asking "What is *the best* approach?" or What should one do?" are questions that are not reasonably answerable as they are subjective and therefore considered as off-topic here. It is certainly easier to memorize the qur'an if one understands Arabic and it is certainly better to learn Arabic first. As understanding is helpful for the memorization process.

Answer (score 0):

Peace. Salaam.

God says in `7:204`, and I'm translating into English

> And if the Qur'an is being read, then `listen` to it and *pay attention*, that you may receive mercy.

And further, in `7:205`,

> And remember your Lord *within yourself*, in humility and in reverence; and without loudness in words, during the morning and the evening. And do not be of the careless ones.

As you know, the Quran was originally, *and still is*, an oral recitation. You *hear* it, typically by those of us who can hear.

Plus, God is saying in `7:204`, when you do hear it, listen to it carefully. Other translations of that ayat say be quite and so on. Al'humdulilah.

Over time, if God wills, you get it.

Indeed, in chapter 75, verses 16-19, God tells us that *He will* take care of your individual Quranic knowledge for you. Of course, there can be other interpretations. Al'humdulilah.

**Point?**

No, you need not know Arabic to begin memorizing, learning or applying the Quran.

One last point. Modern colloquial Arabic, I have been informed from credible sources, is nothing like Quranic Arabic. In other words, native Arabic speakers have the same difficult journey acquiring the Koran and the same level playing field of receiving God's blessings from their beliefs and deeds, as God reminds us over and over in the Quran.

Insha'Allah you can learn more from sister Anse Susan Mouallem about your question in this relatively short and informative talk: https://youtu.be/lrMaZK5MXQY. Note, it has a Sunni school of thought theme for some claims. And God watches and guides, so you have the *option* of checking it out, I can vouch for it.

May God compound your perks of learning the Quran as soon as possible .

Wa'salaam u'Alykum.

Answer (score 0):

Memorizing the Quran will be easier to learn, and remember, if you know Arabic. However, it won't be hard with any other language.